# No such schema 'org.gnome.shell.overrides' Error

Tags: gsettings

The command that I am trying to run is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```

I get the message saying No such schema '*org.gnome.shell.overrides'* error.I am currently using ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the `gnome-shell` package is installed? Those keys are added when installing the shell.

Incidentally, the contents of my `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` variable on my GNOME 3 setup is:

```
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
ubuntu:GNOME
```

You can also use the Mutter window manager (used by GNOME 3) to effect the tiling via:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling true
```